# PHPMailer attachments are showing up as base64-encoded text

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

Here's my PHP code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddAddress('neubert@neubert.com');
$mail->SetFrom('neubert@neubert.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Attachment Test ' . mt_rand(1, 10000000);
$mail->Body = 'See attached!';

$mail->AddStringAttachment('hello, world!', 'test.txt', 'base64', 'application/csv');
$mail->Send();
```

Here's what it looks like in my Gmail inbox:

[image]

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image]

Here's what I see when I click on "Show original" in Gmail:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_av-HS21mQOZlMv59VDZAuEczg"

--_av-HS21mQOZlMv59VDZAuEczg
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--b1_sXvhvmroccaUM1u8XDL1OMveVh8ZiFheK8opqb2i3o8 Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=us-ascii See attached!
--b1_sXvhvmroccaUM1u8XDL1OMveVh8ZiFheK8opqb2i3o8 Content-Type:
application/csv; name="test.txt" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt aGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==
--b1_sXvhvmroccaUM1u8XDL1OMveVh8ZiFheK8opqb2i3o8--
--_av-HS21mQOZlMv59VDZAuEczg
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--b1_sXvhvmroccaUM1u8XDL1OMveVh8ZiFheK8opqb2i3o8
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

See attached!

--b1_sXvhvmroccaUM1u8XDL1OMveVh8ZiFheK8opqb2i3o8
Content-Type: application/csv; name="test.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt

aGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==

--b1_sXvhvmroccaUM1u8XDL1OMveVh8ZiFheK8opqb2i3o8--<img src="https://mandrillapp.com/track/open.php?u=30776766&id=8ee95f6ae4b345d2a87af6f4ea043ca2" height="1" width="1">
--_av-HS21mQOZlMv59VDZAuEczg--
```

According to composer.lock I'm using v6.0.5.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's something freaky going on here - you have two messages stuck together. Is that all your code?

Comment: @Synchro - it is indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea what might be causing this - PHPMailer's MIME boundaries *always* start with `b1`, `b2`, `b3` - but yours starts with `_av`, so I suspect that you have some anti-virus software interfering with your traffic.

Comment: It looks like you're right. I did `echo $this->MIMEBody;` in `postSend()` and got this: https://pastebin.com/ztndU1aJ Here's MIMEHeader: https://pastebin.com/zjaDNkqe

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, but it wasn't an antivirus thing screwing up the boundaries. In my case I had this line in my code:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader( "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" );
```

and removing it solved the problem. I don't remember why I added it in the first place..

Answer (score 0):

Make the mime-type (last parameter) 'text/csv' and change the file name to test.csv. Also provide a comma delimited string as the first parameter to make all the input parameters valid.

Comment: Good catch. I tried to scrub my code of information that could be used to identify me or the company I work for but didn't think about the application/csv bit. Anyway, that doesn't make a difference.